# Python CodeLab Question About Exceptions -- Try, Except ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception, valueerror

The **question**:

"Three variables—x, y, and z—supposedly hold strings of digits, suitable for converting to integers.  Write code that converts these to integers and print the sum of these three integers.  However, if any variable has a value that cannot be converted to an integer, print out, the string "bad value(s) in:  " followed by the names of the variables that have bad values (separated by spaces, in alphabetically ascending order).

For example, if the values of x, y, and z were respectively "3," "9," and "2," then the number 14 would be printed.  On the other hand, if the values were "abc," "15," and "boo," then the output would be:  bad value(s) in:  x z."

---

**Note:** This question is from Turing's Craft CodeLab, which seems to require a specific standard input in order to get the correct answer. I included 'error analyses' with which CodeLab provided me after each attempt to give you a sense of the format that it's looking for.

---

**Attempt** #**1**:

```
error_output = "Bad values in:"
numeric_output = 0
inputs = input().strip().split(" ")
try:
    x = int(inputs[0])
    numeric_output += x
except ValueError:
    error_output += " x"
try:
    y = int(inputs[1])
    numeric_output += y
except ValueError:
    error_output += " y"
try:
    z = int(inputs[2])
    numeric_output += z
except ValueError:
    error_output += " z"
if error_output != "Bad values in:":
    print(error_output)
else:
    print(numeric_output)
```

Though this code runs with no problem on both Idle and Pycharm, it's not the right answer on CodeLab...  Here's CodeLab's '**error analysis**' of my **first attempt**:

---

1. **In every test case**: a)  **stdout is not correct** and b) **nothing was printed to stdout**
2. You almost certainly should be using: **+**
3. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **" "**
4. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **" x"**
5. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **" y"**
6. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **" z"**
7. We think you might want to consider using: **==**
8. We think you might want to consider using: **sum**
9. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **!=**
10. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **. (period)**
11. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **1**
12. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **2**
13. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **[ ]**
14. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **input**
15. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **strip**
16. We think you might want to consider using: **not**

---

My **second attempt**:

```
try:
    print(int(x) + int(y) + int(z))
except ValueError:
    print("bad value(s) in:")
    if not x.isdigit():
        print(' x')
    if not y.isdigit():
        print(' y')
    if not z.isdigit():
        print(' z')
```

'**Error analysis**' of **Attempt** #**2:**

---

1. **In some test cases**: **stdout is not correct**
2. You almost certainly should be using: **=**
3. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **"bad value(s) in:"**
4. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **' x'**
5. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **' y'**
6. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses: **' z'**
7. You almost certainly should be using: **str**
8. We think you might want to consider using: **, (comma)**
9. Solutions with your approach don't usually use: **ValueError**

---

Finally, here's my **third attempt** (which, according to CodeLab, is closest to accurate):

```
try:
    print(int(x) + int(y) + int(z))
except ValueError:
    print("bad value(s) in:",end='')
    if not x.isdigit():
        print('x',end='')
    if not y.isdigit():
        print('y',end='')
    if not z.isdigit():
        print('z',end='')
```

---

'**Error analysis**' of **Attempt** #**3:**

---

1. **In some test cases**: **stdout is not correct**
2. I haven't yet seen a correct solution that uses:  **"bad value(s) in:"**
3. Solutions with your approach don't usually use:  **''**
4. Solutions with your approach don't usually use:  **ValueError**

---

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Please update your code so it is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding spaces before each variable I guess that will help. I also faced these kinds of problems.

```
try:
    print(int(x) + int(y) + int(z))
except ValueError:
    print("bad value(s) in:",end='')
    if not x.isdigit():
        print(' x',end='')
    if not y.isdigit():
        print(' y',end='')
    if not z.isdigit():
        print(' z',end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

that should also work maybe:

```
try:
    print(int(x)+int(y)+int(z))
except ValueError:
    print('bad value(s) in:', end=' ')
    if not x.isdigit():
        print('x', end=' ')
    if not y.isdigit():
        print('y', end=' ')
    if not z.isdigit():
        print('z', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys! I found the answer to be:

```
try:
    sum = int(x) + int(y) + int(z)
    print(sum)
except ValueError:
    print("bad value(s) in:",end=' ')
    if not x.isdigit():
        print('x',end=' ')
    if not y.isdigit():
        print('y',end=' ')
    if not z.isdigit():
        print('z')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum=0
badvalues=""
try:
    sum += int(x)
except ValueError:
    badvalues += " x"
try:
    sum += int(y)
except ValueError:
    badvalues += " y"
try:
    sum += int(z)
except ValueError:
    badvalues += " z"
if badvalues=="":
    print(sum)
else:
    print("bad value(s) in:"+badvalues)
```